# TortoiseSVN Won't Allow Me To Add Any Files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to add files to an SVN repository using TortoiseSVN 1.8.1. I right click on the files and select TortoiseSVN->Add. I then select all the files in the window that pops up and click OK. Upon clicking OK, another dialog box pops up and all the files appear to be successfully added because it says "Added" next to each file and finally it says "Completed!" at the bottom. I click OK, and then right click on the parent directory and click "Commit". I fill out the message box and ensure that all the files I added are checked and they all say "added" under "status". Finally, I click "OK". A box pops up, as it normally does, saying "You haven't entered an issue Number", and I click "Proceed without an issue number". The next box that pops up has a line that says "Adding" with a file that I'm trying to add followed by:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: File '%Path to my file%' is  
Error:  out of date  
Error: File '%File name%' already exists  
Error: You have to update your working copy first.
```

I successfully update my working copy, which has no changes. I also do a successful cleanup. I have tried deleting the parent directory and deleting the base folder altogether and rechecking out the base folder.

I check the repository and there is no file there with the file name of the file being added.

All of the above was through the gui. Using command prompt I got the following:

```
svn status:
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

svn cleanup 5.0.1:
svn: E155009: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with '%PathToBaseRepoFolder%', work item 12841 (sync-file-flags 56 %Path to another file I was unable to add from the base repo folder%)
svn: E720003: Can't set file '%Full path to the other file I was unable to add%' read-write: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

If I do an update and cleanup from the gui, it says both are successful.

We're using http://

I believe the permissions are correct.

Comment: What does `svn status` show? And you did a `svn update`. Right? There are no conflicts? What type of protocol are you using for your server? Is it `file://`, `http://`, or `svn:`? Are the permissions on the files in the repository on the server correct?

Comment: See the update to my question.

Comment: Interesting post with the same error message: http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2013-07/0125.shtml. Could this be encoding/language related? You ran `svn cleanup` successfully on the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was I updated to version 1.8.1 which has a bug. I downloaded version 1.8.0 and it works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 with some files (not all files). I reinstalled TortoiseSVN 1.8.0 and it works now.

Comment: This issue still seems to exist in 1.8.3, just got it during a merge to the trunk, removed the trunk and checked it out again and remerged and it worked!

Answer (score 40):

Happened to me <del>couple of</del> now many times with TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 - 1.8.10. I found [this blog post](http://changilkim.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/svn-cleanup-fails/) which solved this problem once, until it pops up again. It annoyed me so much that I wrote a quick bat file script that I run from desktop.

**Prerequisites**

1. Download and unzip [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) shell tool, e.g. [sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3080803.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3080803.zip)
2. Adjust paths in the commands below to match your environment

**Fix (manual)**

*Run this if you just want to test if this helps*

1. In CMD do `C:\Downloads\sqlite3.exe "C:\src\.svn\wc.db"`
2. Once in sqlite shell run `delete from WORK_QUEUE;`
3. Run tortoise svn clean up

**Fix (automated)**

*If previous step worked for you, consider automating the process with these steps*

1. Go to your *.svn* folder, e.g. *C:\src\.svn*
2. Copy sqlite3 shell tool there
3. Create a `fix-svn.bat` file in that folder
4. Insert scripting code, and adjust paths

   ```
   "C:\src\.svn\sqlite3.exe" wc.db "delete from WORK_QUEUE"
   "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn" cleanup "C:\src"
   ```
5. Save bat file and make a shortcut to your desktop
6. Next time you need to fix it, just run the shortcut on your desktop

Comment: sorry that was in the answer, but text formatting didn't make it much visible. Now updated. Both `.quit` and `.exit` will work.

Comment: i encountered this problem with svn 1.8.10 client after creating a feature branch from a working directory with local changes and then doing a `svn switch` when trying to resolve resulting conflicts.  i think i made the feature branch from the wrong revision.

Comment: I encountered this problem after deleting my .svn directory (don't ask) - this worked perfectly, even in that situation, and I was able to get a clean checkout. Thank you for saving me a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I don't know if this may be an issue. I've sen this error happen when *sparse checkouts* are used. You can adjust what files you see during checkouts via the `--depth` flag and in updates via the `--set-depth` flag. If you `--set-depth=exclude` on certain files, you will see this error if you attempt to add a file.

Try this from the command line. From the ROOT of your working directory:

```
$ svn cleanup
$ svn update --set-depth=infinity
$ svn status
```

Make sure all three of these commands work. Then, try the commit.

Answer (score 2):

Update to the [release candidate](http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.8.x/win32/full/TortoiseSVN-1.8.2.24819-dev-win32-svn-1.8.3.msi) has solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thx, solved it for me. The link seems to be out-dated. The current release candidate can be found in the following dir: http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.8.x/x64/full/

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo svn cleanup
```

resolve my problem